# Organizing Duplicated GameObjects in the Hierarchy

Tags: unity-game-engine, organization, gameobject

In my game world, I have a Tree, that I've created in Blender:

[image]

However in my game world, I need to use over 50+ trees. **So my question is**, how do I reuse my *Tree* object without running into a messy Hierarchy like this:

[image]

Comment: You could group them under an empty GameObject called "Trees"?

Comment: I've done that previously with the fences you see in the screenshot, is that the best solution?

Comment: It's the simplest approach to dealing with lots of identical assets in your hierarchy. Another one (depending on your needs) could be to group your trees into multiple sets based on their purpose/location, eg. "HauntedForest", "StartingForest", etc. There aren't any rules about this - most important thing is to stay consistent to your chosen system throughout your project.

Comment: Awesome, just wanted some confirmation, thank you. You can go ahead and answer the question so I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like something you've started doing already, but just to reaffirm your approach: you can create an empty GameObject (Create > Create Empty) named "Trees" and group your "Tree" objects under it.

In the event that this organization proves too broad, it could be a good idea to place your "Tree" objects under additional subgroups in "Trees", based on their location/purpose - for example, "HauntedForest", "StartingForest", etc.

Ultimately, what's most important is finding an organizational system that works for you, and staying consistent to it throughout your project.